# Ncurses updating panels efficiently

Tags: ncurses

Currently using WSL2, C++20, with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1`, `#include <panel.h>`, `-lpanelw -lncursesw`.

If I have multiple panels of the same size, what would be the most efficient way to update and refresh the current panel that is in focus?

My current approach is to use `hide_panel()` on the rest of the panels, and use `wrefresh()` on the panel I want to focus on. Or would it be better to keep all the panels in the panel stack (visible), and use `top_panel()` whenever I want to switch panels, and update them using `update_panels()` and `doupdate()`?